# Event-driven email actions

Tags: gmail, events

Is there a way to send event-driven emails. For example,

- If I don't hear a response in three days, send this email
- Send this e-mail in three days (delayed response)
- Follow up with this e-mail in five days (CRM-type alert to get a status update)
- Send an e-mail to A,B, & C a week before an event in my Calendar has a location in NYC.
- When I get a response to Email A, put the e-mail thread from Bob re:Update in my inbox

I'm sure there's other events that could trigger e-mail, but these are the ones I'm most interested in. Additionally, I would like an API that could allow me to say "Send {E-mail} when/if {this happens}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I have seen that does something similar to this is [Syphir Rules](http://www.syphir.com/products#rules). I haven't checked if it can do exactly what you want, but it might, since it allows you to define your own rules.

Answer (score 1):

[Followupthen](http://www.followupthen.com) is not as powerful as what you need, but is a really nifty tool for power-user mail usage.